# Convert List<String> to List<Integer> directly

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

After parsing my file " s" contains `AttributeGet:1,16,10106,10111`

So I need to get all the numbers after colon in the attributeIDGet List. I know there are several ways to do it. But is there any way we can **Directly convert `List<String>` to `List<Integer>`.**
As the below code complains about Type mismatch, so I tried to do the Integer.parseInt, but I guess this will not work for List. Here s is String.

```
private static List<Integer> attributeIDGet = new ArrayList<Integer>();

if(s.contains("AttributeGet:")) {
    attributeIDGet = Arrays.asList(s.split(":")[1].split(","));
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No, you need to loop over the array

```
for(String s : strList) intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
```

Comment: What you wrote is effectively looping over the values. But it's an elegant solution, nonetheless.
Just to add to that. With the new lambda methods.
`intList.addAll(strList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Or even 
strList.foreach(s->intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));

Comment: You can use Lambda to convert this list

Answer (score 104):

Using Java8:

```
stringList.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: if send StringList to method (List<Interger>) can not. I think need create new List<Interger> and loop

Comment: @Jagadeesh: Integer::parseInt throws a NumberFormatException if the string is not an integer. You can filter out a non-integer elements using for example StringUtils::isNumeric from Apache Commons.

Answer (score 11):

Using lambda:

`strList.stream().map(org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils::toInt).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Lambda functions of Java 8 to achieve this without looping

```
    String string = "1, 2, 3, 4";
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(string.split(",")).stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 9):

[Guava Converters](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Converter.html) do the trick.

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;

final Iterable<Long> longIds = 
    Longs.stringConverter().convertAll(
        Splitter.on(',').trimResults().omitEmptyStrings()
            .splitToList("1,2,3"));
```

Answer (score 8):

No, you will have to iterate over each element:

```
for(String number : numbers) {
   numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(number)); 
}
```

The reason this happens is that there is no straightforward way to convert a list of one type into *any other* type. Some conversions are not possible, or need to be done in a specific way. Essentially the conversion depends on the objects involved and the context of the conversion so there is no "one size fits all" solution. For example, what if you had a `Car` object and a `Person` object. You can't convert a `List<Car>` into a `List<Person>` directly since it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 7):

If you use [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) this is what you can do, see [Lists#transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)

```
    String s = "AttributeGet:1,16,10106,10111";


    List<Integer> attributeIDGet = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(s.contains("AttributeGet:")) {
        List<String> attributeIDGetS = Arrays.asList(s.split(":")[1].split(","));
        attributeIDGet =
        Lists.transform(attributeIDGetS, new Function<String, Integer>() {
            public Integer apply(String e) {
                return Integer.parseInt(e);
            };
        });
    }
```

Yep, agree with above answer that's it's bloated, but stylish. But it's just another way.

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to use lambdas from Java 8, you can use the following code sample.

```
final String text = "1:2:3:4:5";
final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(text.split(":")).stream()
  .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

No use of external libraries. Plain <s>old</s> new Java!

Comment: I am getting this syntax error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int inside map function. Can you plz help me with this

Comment: @SonalMaheshwari What version of Java are you using (and on what environment)? I'm on `1.8.0_05` on Mac OS X. Can you also provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) (on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or an equivalent)?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use stream to convert List of Strings to List of integers?
like below

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("10", "30", "40",
            "50", "60", "70"));
List<Integer> integerList = stringList.stream()
            .map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

complete operation could be something like this

```
String s = "AttributeGet:1,16,10106,10111";
List<Integer> integerList = (s.startsWith("AttributeGet:")) ?
    Arrays.asList(s.replace("AttributeGet:", "").split(","))
    .stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())
    : new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Streams and Lambda:

```
newIntegerlist = listName.stream().map(x-> 
    Integer.valueOf(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above line of code will convert the List of type `List<String>` to `List<Integer>`.

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way (that I know of), of doing that in Java.

Basically you'll have to transform each entry from String to Integer.

What you're looking for could be achieved in a more functional language, where you could pass a transformation function and apply it to every element of the list... but such is not possible (it would still apply to every element in the list).

**Overkill:**

You can, however use a Function from Google Guava (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) to simulate a more functional approach, if that is what you're looking for.

If you're worried about iterating over the list twice, then instead of split use a Tokenizer and transform each integer token to Integer before adding to the list.

Comment: Using `Function` here is way overkill.

Comment: I know, it won't achieve anything in terms of eficiency and it *is* overkill, I only wanted to point it out as a way of simulating a more "functional" approach. Unfortunately, you're only mimicking that behavior and usually end up with bloated code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example to show power of Guava. Although, this is not the way I write code, I wanted to pack it all together to show what kind of functional programming Guava provides for Java.

```
Function<String, Integer> strToInt=new Function<String, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(String e) {
         return Integer.parseInt(e);
    }
};
String s = "AttributeGet:1,16,10106,10111";

List<Integer> attributeIDGet =(s.contains("AttributeGet:"))?
  FluentIterable
   .from(Iterables.skip(Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf(";,")).split(s)), 1))
   .transform(strToInt)
   .toImmutableList():
   new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava transform method as below,

List intList =  Lists.transform(stringList, Integer::parseInt);

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reto1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double suma = 0, promedio = 0;
        String IRCA = "";
        int long_vector = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());    
        int[] Lista_Entero = new int[long_vector];       // INSTANCE INTEGER LIST
        String[] lista_string = new String[long_vector]; // INSTANCE STRING LIST
        Double[] lista_double = new Double[long_vector];
        lista_string = input.nextLine().split(" ");     //  INPUT STRING LIST
    input.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < long_vector; i++) {
        Lista_Entero[i] = Integer.parseInt(lista_string[i]); // CONVERT INDEX TO INDEX FROM STRING UNTIL INTEGER AND ASSIGNED TO NEW INTEGER LIST
        suma = suma + Lista_Entero[i];
    }
```