# Java ArrayList<Integer> to ArrayList<String> & vice versa

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm wondering how to convert `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Integer>`.

I have this code:

```
ArrayList<String> sNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(3);

sNumbers.add(numbers.toString());
System.out.println(sNumbers);//for testing
```

I'm getting this:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

And that's my question: How can I reverse this procces (Get one line of numbers and put it in numbers `ArrayList`)

It should be like this:

```
sNumbers
0 [1, 2, 3] --> 

numbers
0 [1]
1 [2]
2 [3]
(without brackets)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a simple algorithm for turning the string representation of an array back into an array

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> arrayStringToIntegerArrayList(String arrayString){
    String removedBrackets = arrayString.substring(1, arrayString.length() - 1);
    String[] individualNumbers = removedBrackets.split(",");
    ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String numberString : individualNumbers){
        integerArrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(numberString.trim()));
    }
    return integerArrayList;
}
```

You would call it with

```
System.out.println(arrayStringToIntegerArrayList(sNumbers.get(0)));
```

and it will return an `ArrayList<Integer>` with the values `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 10):

Invoking `toString` on a `List<Integer>` will return a `String` representation of the `List` (i.e. `"[1,2,3]"`), not a `List<String>` containing a `String` representation of each of its contents.

You must fill your `String`s manually:

```
for (Integer i: numbers) {
    sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

**Note**

There is probably some fancier stuff you could do with Java 8 in terms of declarative vs imperative coding - unfortunately i don't have the jdk installed at the moment.

Hopefully someone else will pick this up and answer for Java 8.

Comment: This is correct, but I meant something else. When Array numbers is changing, I save it to sNumbers. Going your way I don't have any separator between 2 arrays. I just wanted to avoid 2 dimensional Arrays

Comment: The way I read the question, they're more than happy with getting the string representation of the ArrayList (i.e. a single String: `[1, 2, 3]`), they just want to be able to reverse that process; take the String `[1, 2, 3]` and create an `ArrayList<Integer>` with three elements, 1, 2, and 3. This doesn't seem like it answers the question being asked at all (to me, your understanding obviously differs).

Comment: Yes, I agree. When I getting new content of numbers (after saving numbers in sNumbers I cleaning it) I want to put it to sNumbers Array, then I want to pick one row from array. I can paste all code if you want.

Comment: Although I agree [Austin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2033671/austin)'s answer seems to specifically respond to the question details, the general scope is, and I quote, to "to convert `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Integer>`". [Beri](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4086177/beri)'s answer and mine address this with what should be considered as best practices for Java, given the limited scope. I cannot think of **any** real life use case where Austin's answer could be preferable.

Comment: Consider the `String` representation of a `List` is already iterating its items to produce the result. Parsing it back to build another `List` (of different parametrized type) is pointless, costly, and would denote a serious misconception of how Java collections and `String` representation of objects actually work, unless I'm missing an academical point here.

Comment: I still learning java the way of trials and errors, I'll read about Java 8 and collection. Augustin's answer just better matches my level of learning java. Maybe I write question unclearly, but thank you all.

Comment: @Jump3r you're welcome. I recommend you don't use Austin's solution in production code, but for learning purposes, why not :)

Answer (score 6):

As @mena mentioned you can do it with:

pure Java:

```
List<String> sNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Integer i: numbers) {
    sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

JDK 8 - map:

```
List<String> sNumbers = numbers.stream().map(
    n -> n.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()
);
```

Or use guava library, it's similar to JDK8.

I assume you can find more examples here:
[Convert List<String> to List<Integer> directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706721/convert-liststring-to-listinteger-directly)

Comment: Plus 1 for the Java 8 part!

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array

```
for(int i : numbers ) sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following loops:

```
//number 1
for(Integer number : numbers){
            sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(number));
    }

//number 2
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
    sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(numbers.get(i)));
}

//number 3
int j = 0;
while(numbers.size() > j){
    sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(numbers.get(j)));
    j++;
}

//number 4  
Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    sNumbers.add(String.valueOf(iterator.next()));
}
```