# How to convert an ArrayList of Strings to integers without any library methods?

Tags: java

I want to convert an ArrayList of Strings to integers in Java.

My attempt:

```
ArrayList number = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("45","9","77"))
int res = 0;
System.out.println(res);
for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
    res = res * 10 + number.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, to "an integer" ?

Comment: to int like 45,9,77

Comment: 45,9,77 isn't an int

Comment: Do you mean `ArrayList<String>` into `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: `list.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(toList())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert List<String> to List<Integer> directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706721/convert-liststring-to-listinteger-directly)

Comment: List<String> stringNumberList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("45","9","77"))
            int res = 0;

            for (String s : stringNumberList) {
                res = Integer.parseInt(s);
                System.out.println(res);
            }           
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something here. You have a `List` of `String`s, and you should iterate over the characters of each of these `String`s separately in order to convert it to an `int`. This means you need two nested loops.

Though there are much easier ways of doing it (with `Integer.parseInt()`), here's an implementation based on the logic of your original code:

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("45","9","77");
List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
for (String number : numbers) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        res = res * 10 + (number.charAt(i) - '0');
    }  
    output.add(res);         
}
System.out.println (output);
```

Output:

```
[45, 9, 77]
```

Comment: it's not really clear whether he means one single int or a List of int/Integer. with one Stream -> map (r -> return Integer.parseInt(r)) he might be able to do what he wants

Comment: @Stultuske I understood that each String should be converted to an int separatelly, and the OP's comment confirms it.

Comment: so why the need for a nested loop? using a stream to iterate once and return the Integer value, afterwards collected into a List should do it